# JavaScript - entering Minutes:seconds and sum totals

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I'm working in Acrobat Pro 9 (using JavaScript), and I'm trying to these form fields to work correctly. The user needs to enter a duration of time (MM:ss) in several fields, and then have the total duration sum up at the bottom, also displaying as MM:ss.

I had used this code to create the total Time

```
//Get the total from hidden field
var v1 = getField("Total minutes").value;

// Define a constant to be used below:
var numSecondsInMinute = 60;

// The total number of seconds:
var numSeconds = v1*60;

// Extract the number of minutes from the total number of seconds - rounded down:
var numMinutes = Math.floor(numSeconds / numSecondsInMinute);

// Subtract the extracted number of minutes (converted to seconds) from the total number of 
// seconds to get the remaining number of seconds:
numSeconds -= (numMinutes * numSecondsInMinute);

// Build a string from the final number of minutes and number of seconds in (MM:SS) format:
var finalTime = "(" + numMinutes + ":" + numSeconds + ")";

// Display the final time:
event.value=finalTime;
```

But that doesn't help with getting a total our of various MM:ss fields (e.g. 1:30 for a minute and a half, or 2:15, or 7:00).

Any ideas?

Comment: If, as it seems from the code, you get the total number of minutes at the beginning (the value of  `v1`), what you want is impossible. You need the total number of seconds in the beginning (so they can be grouped in minutes and seconds). If you indeed, get the total number of seconds in the beginning, please edit your code, so it gets obvious. (the field should be called "Total seconds"). Or, in another case - are you getting your minutes as a float number?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Acrobat JavaScript util.scand() method to convert the strings entered into the various MM:ss fields into JavaScript Date objects, perform the math, then convert the result back to a string using the util.printd() method, then set that value as the "Total Minutes" value.